# Optimizing conditionals which trigger I18n.l date formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The Model `TravelReport` has two attributes: `departure_date` and `arrival_date`

The helper `arrival_and_departure_months(travel_report)` results in the following strings:

```
'February - July 2014'
'December 2013 - January 2014'
'March 2014'
''
```

Depending if the start and end month is in the same year. To make things worse both can be nil too which results in an empty string.

This is the current method:

```
def arrival_and_departure_months(travel_report)
  if travel_report.arrival_date && travel_report.departure_date
    output = I18n.l travel_report.arrival_date, :format => '%B'

    if travel_report.arrival_date.year != travel_report.departure_date.year
      output += I18n.l travel_report.arrival_date, :format => ' %Y'
    else
      if travel_report.arrival_date.month == travel_report.departure_date.month
        return I18n.l(travel_report.departure_date, :format => '%B %Y')
      end
    end

    output + I18n.l(travel_report.departure_date, :format => ' - %B %Y')
  else
    ''
  end
end
```

How can we simplify or optimize the code? This collection of `if` and `else` is no eye candy at all.

Comment: What is bothering you here? Once the method is defined properly, you will not have to look at it again. It might not be a "eye candy at all" but you will not have to deal with it every day, just once to define it. (also I don't a better way to define this method, your code is fine IMO).

Comment: I feel your pain. I'm not a 100% sure but maybe a regex over the complete string could solve this problem with way less code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of some if conditions and get a cleaner code by using regular expressions to replace not needed parts of the string:

```
def arrival_and_departure_months(travel_report)
  if travel_report.arrival_date && travel_report.departure_date
    output = I18n.l(travel_report.arrival_date, :format => '%B %Y') + 
             I18n.l(travel_report.departure_date, :format => ' - %B %Y')
    output = output.gsub(/([^ ]+ \d{4}) - \1/, '\1')
    output.gsub(/([^ ]+) (\d{4}) - ([^ ]+) \2/, '\1 - \3 \2')
  else
    ''
  end
end
```

You can check and play around with the regular expressions here:

- http://rubular.com/r/mY3SiN7N14
- http://rubular.com/r/1p5P5BUCVs